# VHDL Clock Question

Tags: vhdl

What is the difference between these statements in VHDL:

1. if (clk'event and clk='1') then
2. if rising_edge(clk) then

Are they equivalent ?  Do you produce the same behavior (outputs) ?  Why would one be used versus the other ?

Also is one synthesizable versus the other ?  Which is better for synthesis correct coding ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205202/clkevent-vs-rising-edge

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not exactly equivalent. The first variation

```
if (clk'event and clk='1') then
```

only works correctly if the previous state of the clock was in fact '0'. This works fine in most cases, but won't catch unusual cases, such as when the previous state was 'U', 'W', 'X' or 'Z'.

The second variation uses `rising_edge()`<sup>1</sup>, which specifically checks whether the previous state was '0' or 'L' and the new state is '1' or 'H'.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can see the actual definition on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15205202/2060012)

Comment: So would it be correct to say it might be better to use rising edge to catch all possible cases if you are using U W X Z states ?

Comment: @sheeple: Yes, that was the recommendation of my teacher when I learned VHDL 10 years ago. There still seems to be old VHDL code and ways of working on the internet.

Comment: Okay, because many texts still use the if (clk'event and clk='1') then variation.  Which is better for synthesis ?

Comment: rising_edge and falling_edge. Because they require a change from an effective '0' and effective '1' behavioral simulation will match synthesis models.